# Git Revert to Nth commit. How to find what N is

Tags: git, version-control, revert

I need to do

```
git revert HEAD~N
```

Where N is a commit possibly 25-35 commits ago. How can I find what N is without reverting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use the hash of the commit you want to revert instead? The `HEAD~N` syntax is just a shortcut for specifying a commit in relative terms; it gets resolved into a hash anyway by Git.

First, do `git log` and find the commit hash of the commit you want to revert to. (If you want a more condensed log, you can use `git log --oneline`.)

Then do `git revert <hash>`.

Also note that if you're wanting to revert ***to*** a commit, as opposed to just reverting ***a*** commit, you actually want to use [`git reset`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-reset) rather than [`git revert`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-revert).

Comment: @sehe Which is why the answer doesn't say it does? I made a typo initially, but quickly edited it.

Comment: you're so right. I misread the OP. Sry. (Hmm. it seems like someone else downvoted your answer, I hope it wasn't because of my comment...)